# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{2\cos(ax)-\sqrt3}{\pi-6x}$, for positive integer $a$ satisfying $\cos(a\pi/6)=\sqrt{3}/2$ and $\cos(t+ab)=\cos(t+b)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

> Let $a$ be a positive integer such that $\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\cos(\theta+a\cdot\beta)=\cos(\theta+\beta)$ For any $\theta,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Calculate
> $$
>     \lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{2\cos(ax)-\sqrt{3}}{\pi-6x}
> $$

Proof.

For $\cos\left(\frac{a\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. We have the following table.

$\cos(x)$ table of periodic values with $2n\pi$ intervals.

[image]

Be $\frac{a\pi}{6}=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence $a=1+12n$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Taking this into account, let us assume that it is $a=1+12(0)=1$, so
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{2\cos(x)-\sqrt{3}}{\pi-6x} \tag1$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{\sqrt{3}-2\cos(x)}{6x-\pi} \tag2$$

By applying L’Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{(\sqrt{3}-2\cos(x))'}{(6x-\pi)'} \tag3$$
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{-2\sin(x)}{6} \tag4$$
$$\frac{-2\sin(\frac{\pi}{6})}{6} \tag5$$
$$\frac{-2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{6} \tag6$$
$$-\frac{1}{6} \tag7$$
This is what I managed to do, I'm not sure it's correct; I would appreciate it if you could help me clear up this doubt.

Comment: So that you don't have to *assume* a value for $a$ ... Consider the given relation $\cos(\theta+a\beta)=\cos(\theta+\beta)$, with $\theta=0$ and $\beta=a$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sqrt{3}-2\text{cos}(x)}{6x-\pi}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{6}
\end{equation*}

This was a very close attempt at a solution! The only mistake was missing a change of sign, please note that the derivative of cos(x) is -sin(x), with this you will get the positive equivalent of your answer.

Comment: The argument of $\cos$ in your answer is missing an $a$. In fact, your whole answer ignores it.

Comment: @AlexM.: This answer seems to be assuming $a=1$.